# Concat video files of different resolutions using FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I am using FFmpeg to concat videos in my android application.I have followed some of the steps to merge videos of different formats. For mp4 videos, i have to convert all input files to MPEG-2 TS files and then merge all the .ts files to get an output mp4 file.

- I have a problem in merging the videos if they are of different
  resolutions(say one is 640*480 and the other is 1280*720).The output
  video does not merge properly(sometimes it throws an error in
  Streams). Is there any way to handle this without losing the quality
  of videos?
- Lets say i am merging two videos one with audio and the other without
  audio.When i try to merge these two i am getting errors in Audio
  Streams.Is there any way to handle this also(videos should be merged with or without audio)?

I am facing problems in above two things and spent more time without success.
Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the ffmpeg command line tool or the API? You mention "errors", but you do not show them.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg API and the parameters are passed from android.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1136854/101823

Answer (score 0):

For merging videos you need to work with the same resolution, you should scale the 640x480 video or compress the 1280x720, it is up to you. I would recommend you compress the bigger one it is faster.

Moreover, for merging videos you need a media file with audio and video part. You can create a silence audio with the same duration of your video and after you can add it to your video. Videos should be merged with audio.

```
ffmpeg -ar 48000 -t 60 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -i /dev/zero -ab 128K -f mp2 -acodec mp2 -y silence.mp2

ffmpeg -i video_without_audio.mpg -i silence.mp2 video_to_merge.mpg
```

Comment: Alvaro, Thanks for the reply. /dev/zero is the input video file, right? Also how do we know if there is audio or not? Can these be done automatically by FFmpeg because it takes so much of time for conversions which is making the app bad.

Comment: /dev/zero is not a video file, this command is to create a dummy audio to join in your video, without audio you can not merge videos. To know if there is an audio stream, use ffmpeg output, with option -i you can check the streams, stream #0.0 video and stream #0.1 audio.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, i will check it out.Is there a way to concat video files of different formats directly in single step without conversions because it takes more time? Also i am having problems in building latest ffmpeg.Is there any steps to use ffmpeg libraries(after building separately) with android to make a shared library that comprises all of the ffmpeg commands?